# how to convert string data from columns to date in kusto

Tags: azure, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am writing a kusto query in azure which extracts data from a column called RawData and puts that date into another column(Date). Now this Date column has the date data but it is in string format. How to convert it into date format so i can apply date functions on it?

```
UserLogs 
| project Date=substring(RawData, 0, 22), RawData
| project Date, RawData=substring(RawData, 24, 150)
| where RawData has "Login" and Date > ago(15m)
```

whose result look like :-

[image]

The sample date looks something like
[image]

Comment: can you please share sample input data.

Comment: hi @RitikaNalwaya updated it in the question itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `todatetime()` you can covert a column datatype to *date* format. After converting column to date any date functions can be applied.

**Sample code**

```
datatable (Computer: string,RawData : string) [
"h01","2023-04-06 09:42:00.154 Login by user abc",
"h02","2023-04-06 09:42:00.154 Login by user Jeff",
"h09","2023-04-06 09:42:00.154 Login by user predom"
]
| project  Date=todatetime(substring(RawData, 0, 22)), RawData=substring(RawData, 24, 150)
| where  RawData  has  "Login"  and  Date > ago(15m)
```

**Result**

[image]

**Result schema**

[image]

Comment: Hi Ritika, when I use this query it does not return anything! I removed the Date > ago(15m) so now it returns everything? do i need to convert or apply any more functions here to get only 15 mins of data?

Comment: could you help me with this ?

Comment: @Aviator can you please confirm *UserLogs* table has latest logs data?

Comment: @Aviator `ago(15m)` will return us data which is 15 minutes prior to current time. Please make sure source data has some data which suffice the condition.

Comment: thanks a lot Ritika, this has been great help !